# What is $P(A \cup B)$ given $P(A)$ and$ P(B)$, independent events

Tags: probability

Given $P(A) = 0.60$ and $P(B) = 0.70$, what is $P(A \cup B)$? In other words, if there is a $60\text{%}$ chance that it rains today, and a $70\text{%}$ chance that it rains tomorrow, what is the probability that it rains either today or tomorrow? Also, how does this work (adding probabilities)? I've been trying to think this through for an hour.

Comment: For reference of why the good answers below are valid here is a link to the [inclusion-exclusion principle](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion–exclusion_principle).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Use $P(A\cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A)P(B)$

Comment: Thanks for the response, but could you explain why that works, or at least show me where I can see something that explains it?

Comment: if $A$ and $B$ are independent, then $P(A\cap B) = P(A)P(B)$

Comment: OK, that's good to know, but why is that true?

Comment: so that you can use $P(A) = 0.6$, and $P(B) = 0.7$

Comment: Oh, i get it. The intersection is where they overlap, so it's where both events occur.

Answer (score 2):

In general,
$$
P(A\,\,\text{or} \,\, B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\,\,\text{and} \,\, B)
$$
for any events $A$ and $B$. So in order to calculate $P(A\,\,\text{or} \,\, B)$ we generally need all three quantities on the right. However, when $A$ and $B$ are independent, then, by definition,
$$
P(A\,\,\text{and}\,\, B)=P(A)P(B)
$$
and thus we only need $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ to determine $P(A\,\,\text{or}\,\, B)$.

Comment: But according to this, P(A or B) = .6 + .7 + .6 * .7 = 172%, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: The OP is missing a minus sign in the first equation...

Comment: @5xum hahah thought so.

Comment: Indeed, thanks for catching that @5xum.